# Drawing a rainbow colored ring in android

Tags: android, android-view, ondraw, sweepgradient

I've been trying to draw a rainbow colored ring in android using the following code:

```
public void init(){
    ringPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    ringPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    ringPaint.setStrokeWidth(8f);
    ringPaint.setShader(new SweepGradient(0, 0, COLORS2, null));
}



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2f,getHeight()/2f ,getHeight()/2f - 16f,ringPaint);
}
```

the value for `COLOR2` is the following:

```
final int[] COLORS2 = new int[]{Color.parseColor("#33004c"), Color.parseColor("#4600d2"),
                                Color.parseColor("#0000ff"), Color.parseColor("#0099ff"),
                                Color.parseColor("#00eeff"),Color.parseColor("#00FF7F"),
                                Color.parseColor("#48FF00"),Color.parseColor("#B6FF00"),
                                Color.parseColor("#FFD700"),Color.parseColor("#ff9500"),
                                Color.parseColor("#FF6200"),Color.parseColor("#FF0000"),
                                Color.parseColor("#33004c")};
```

The problem is that I'm only getting a subset of the colors, maybe 3 or 4 of the distinct colors in the array and I'm not entirely sure why, can anyone offer some suggestion as to why this is the case?

[image]

Comment: can you screenshot your ring?

Comment: @Jacky...done..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should specify center of view instead of 0,0 when create SweepGradient

look at example please

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private Paint ringPaint;

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        ringPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        ringPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        ringPaint.setStrokeWidth(8f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        ringPaint.setShader(new SweepGradient(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, COLORS2, null));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2f, getHeight() / 2f, getHeight() / 2f - 16f, ringPaint);
    }
}
```

[image]